# GSON deserialization with return types defined in ENUM

Tags: java, gson

In fromJson method, I need the second parameter to be the value passed.

I am not sure how to go about making the second parameter a variable which has the value that I want the json object to be de-serialized to.

```
public void deserializeFunc(value, typeToConvert)
{
     //someothercode
    Object val = gson.fromJson(value, typeToConvert);
    //someothercode
}
```

`value` is a String,
`typeToConvert` could be Integer or Float or some other Class object.

I need to maintain the list of types to convert in an Enum and then pass it, but I am not sure of how to use the enum value.

```
public enum typeToConvert {
   Integer,
   Float,
   Response,
   ...
}
```

Comment: Those are already predefined classes, i don't think you need an enum here